# How to populate some default users in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on trying to get Devise working in my Rails app.  I'm a new Rails user.  What's the proper way to add a few default users?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The normal way to set up any default data in Rails is by adding the data in `db/seeds.rb`:

```
user1 = User.create :name => "User1", :email => "user1@example.com", :password => "user123"
```

Depending on your validations and devise features you might need to enter more fields. In order to use that data you just call `rake db:seed`.

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

Comment: you can also add code like: if Rails.env == 'development' if you have environment specific seeds

Comment: Also, `rake db:reset` will do a complete reset of the database, including re-seed for you. Comes in handy.

Answer (score 2):

[Faker](http://rubygems.org/gems/faker) is a great option if you don't want to write all of the users out by hand.

This [faker tutorial](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-gems-plugins-and-engines/using-faker-to-pre-populate-a-dev-database) shows how to use the gem to populate the db in a relatively simple rake task.

Comment: Second link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Addition : The below method won't work.

```
User.new
User.name = "Bob"
User.password = "Bob123"
User.password_confirmation = "Bob123"
User.save!   ## Exception raised => Password field cannot be blank.
```

As Devise runs its internal methods, like, 'generating encrypted password from password', after 'new' is called on User. So, User.new raises Exception, saying password is not supplied. Instead use, either

```
User.create({ :name => "Bob", ... })    # or 
User.new({ :name => "Bob", ... }).save
```